# Returns and Factors for European Market Kenneth French Database

Tags: returns, regression, factor-models, fama-french

I am planning to estimate Fama-French model for mutual funds with European equity scope. I am thinking about using the European factors from Kenneth French database, which are computed in USD.

The question I faced is: how does Kenneth French data-set arrive at USD returns for European market? Do they assume hedging?

http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/f-f_3developed.html

Answer (score 2):

The paper you should read to understand how they build that dataset is the following:

- [Fama-French (2012): Size, value, and momentum in international stock returns](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X12000931)

At the end of section 2 the authors write:

> Finally, like the tests of Fama and French (1998), Griffin (2002),
>   Hou, Karolyi, and Kho (2011), and others, our tests of international
>   asset pricing models ignore exchange rate risk. This means we
>   implicitly assume either (i) complete purchasing power parity
>   (relative prices of goods are the same everywhere and an exchange rate
>   is just the ratio of the nominal prices of any good in two countries)
>   or (ii) the assets we consider cannot be used to hedge exchange risk.
>   See, e.g., Fama and Farber (1979) and Adler and Dumas (1983), for the
>   theory, and Dumas and Solnik (1995) and Zhang (2006) for empirical
>   tests that allow for exchange risk. Exchange risks are thus a
>   potential problem in our inferences.

I think this answers your question.